# Empty result set in Java and mySQL despite my query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am a college student working with Java, and my most recent assignment requires retrieving information from and manipulating a relational database using a combination of Java and mySQL code with JDBC. All of the result sets work as intended except for the last set, rs11. It is supposed to handle information regarding the time a meeting with ID1081 starts, the time a meeting with ID1081 ends, and the day of the week a meeting with ID1081 ends. However, it is empty despite the fact that I gave it the below query:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql8part4 = "SELECT * FROM TIME_SLOT WHERE TIME_SLOT.MEETING_ID = '1081'";
ResultSet rs11 = stmt.executeQuery(sql8part4);
```

Additional information: Connection (represented by the variable `conn`) and statement (represented by the variable `stmt`) have been initialized properly and the result sets that are not rs11 work perfectly. I remembered to use a `while(rs11.next())` loop for the display, and get an "Illegal operation on empty result set" exception when I try to use a do-while loop. So I know the issue isn't just me not printing it correctly.

The TA I have been assigned to work with can't see any issues that would cause the empty result set, so I hope that the community here can help. As a final note, I am very inexperienced with code and so will probably have a lot of questions about the solutions you come up with.

Comment: Take the sql query and run it against the database using a sql client and see what you get.

Comment: If the result set is empty, then the result set is empty. What exactly do you expect us to do? BTW note that 1081 is not the same as ID1081!

Comment: You may get more help if you provide more of the Java and a stacktrace that shows the line number where the exception occurred.

Comment: @yoidilip I can go try that.

Comment: @JeffMiller Okay. I can provide more code.

This is the code for querying one of the functional result sets. I know this works, but it might contain some clues for why rs11 doesn't.

    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql4part1 = "SELECT MEETING.MEETING_NM FROM MEETING WHERE MEETING.MEETING_ID = '1105'";
    ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery(sql4part1);

Comment: @JeffMiller And this is the loop that I am using for printing:

while(rs11.next()){
 System.out.println("Inside resultset 11");
 String startTime = rs11.getString("START_TIME");
 String endTime = rs11.getString("END_TIME");
 String dayOfWeek = rs11.getString("DAY_OF_WEEK");
 System.out.println("Starts at:" + startTime + "\nEnds at: " + endTime + "\nOccurs on " + dayOfWeek);
   }

Do you need anything else?

Comment: Nevermind. I received word that the database was changed-- something that I was not notified of until a few minutes ago. It works now. Thanks for the help! I will keep this all in mind when drafting questions in the future.